# How to export TFS WITs from Chrome

Tags: tfs, export-to-excel

I have colleagues who need to export TFS WITs that they access through Chrome to Excel.  They do not have Visual Studio.  So they are asking me to export these items out of Visual Studio.  Not sure if there's any add-ins that do this but i haven't been able to find any.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the extension : [VSTS Open in Excel](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=blueprint.vsts-open-work-items-in-excel)

> This extension requires Microsoft Excel and one of the following
>   clients to be installed:
>
> - [Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#visual-studio-enterprise-2017) or later
> - [Team Foundation Server Office® Integration 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#team-foundation-server-office-integration-2017) or later

So, if no VS installed, you can install the [Team Foundation Server Office® Integration 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#team-foundation-server-office-integration-2017). It's about 110 MB, much smaller the VS.

Then you can **create a query** and open the query in Excel **via web portal** to export the work items.

[image]

Comment: @user459962 Have you resolved the issue by the answer? any update?